# replace a value in a multi dimention array- phap

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, replace

I need to replace all the total values with the corresponding subtraction of start and end values. Values are come from a sql result
Any help how to do that?
For Ex :

12.30 - 5.00 = 7.30

15.30 - 7.00 = 8.30

16.30 - 9.00 = 7.30

Existing array

```
array(184) {
   [1]=>
      array(3) {
         ["start"]=>
         string(4) "5.00"
         ["end"]=>
         string(4) "12.30"
         ["total"]=>
         string(4) "1.00"
      }
   [2]=>
      array(3) {
         ["start"]=>
         string(4) "7.00"
         ["end"]=>
         string(4) "15.30"
         ["total"]=>
         string(4) "1.00"
      }
   [3]=>
      array(3) {
         ["start"]=>
         string(4) "9.00"
         ["end"]=>
         string(4) "16.30"
         ["total"]=>
         string(4) "1.00"
      }
    ... // more records are there
 }
```

Replaced final array

```
 array(184) {
    [1]=>
       array(3) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(4) "5.00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(4) "12.30"
        ["total"]=>
        string(4) "7.30"
    }
    [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(4) "7.00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(4) "15.30"
        ["total"]=>
        string(4) "8.30"
   }
   [3]=>
     array(3) {
       ["start"]=>
       string(4) "9.00"
       ["end"]=>
       string(4) "16.30"
       ["total"]=>
       string(4) "7.30"
   }
... // more records are there
 }
```

Comment: Do we diff time or base(10) numbers here? For example 5.20 - 4.30 = 0.90 in base(10) and 5.20 - 4.30 = 0.50 time wise. I assume it's time, but wanna be sure before i give you answer (cause both answers already posted are based on decimals, not time).

Comment: @MichalPrajsnar, you have good point here.

Comment: Added time-based difference answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your code:

```
function timeDiff($first, $second) {
    return str_replace(':', '.', 
        strtotime(str_replace('.', ':', $second)) - 
        strtotime(str_replace('.', ':', $first))
    );
}
```

Then assign your array to `$array` variable and use code provided in [Akam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646111/akam)'s answer, just change `y-x` to `timeDiff(x,y)`:

```
foreach($array as &$v){
    $v['total'] = timeDiff($v['start'], $v['end']);
}
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanx alot. I used your method and added some more of mine and finally make it work. :) you guys are rocks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach($array as &$v){
 $v['total'] = $v['end']-$v['start'];
}
```

Comment: Message: Undefined index: start 
Filename: controllers/reports_generator.php.

Comment: `$array` should be your array variable name~

Comment: Cause you should do it for every single array containing "start", "end" and "total" keys, not only once for main array... which doesn't change the fact that it won't work for every date passed, cause you can't simply `x-y` for time. It works for your example, but won't work for mine (check my comment again).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like what @Akam suggest or you can do the long way

```
    $array = array(
        array('start' => '5.00', 'end' => '12.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
        array('start' => '7.00', 'end' => '15.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
        array('start' => '9.00', 'end' => '16.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
   );

    array_walk($array, 
        function(&$arr) { 
           $arr['total'] = $arr['end'] - $arr['start']; 
        }
    );

   var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$array = array(
        array('start' => '5.00', 'end' => '12.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
        array('start' => '7.00', 'end' => '15.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
        array('start' => '9.00', 'end' => '16.30', 'total' => '1.00'),
   );

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
     $array[$key]['total'] = $val['start']+$val['end'];
 }

 var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($i=1; $i<= count($my_array); $i++){

        $end= str_replace('.',':',$my_array[$i]['end']);
        $start = str_replace('.',':',$my_array[$i]['start']);

        $my_array[$i]['total']  =gmdate("H:i",strtotime($end)-strtotime($start));
    }
```

Here I used the for loop to change all the occurrences in my array. And finally print it in the H:i format.